# R6030 CRT Not initialized

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, atl

We are facing an issue at the customer site; the Customer has built his application using VS2010 Runtime dated 19th Feb 2011 and version 10.0.40219.1
The customer’s app uses our dll, which is also built using the VS2010 Runtime but slightly older version.

We have an option in out  installer where you can skip the installation of VC Runtime re-distributable, here the customer would have skipped as he already has the runtime installed.

The problem here is if the customer’s app starts first and then loads our DLL, then there is no issue. but in another scenario if the customer’s App loads only msvcr100.dll and does not load msvcp100.dll
And then later when our dll is loaded , then we get an error “R6030 CRT Not initialized”

Is this because of runtime incompatibility issue, should the runtime and the application be compiled with exact same version ?

Comment: This issue was resolved, what i did is created a memory dump when this issue occurs, when analyzing this dump, we found that one of the application dlls was doing a LoadLibrary in its DllMain. when this was addressed the issue was resolved, so the bottom line is never call LoadLibrary in Dllmain

Comment: This isn't strictly related to the specific issue, but moving to VS 2015 grants you binary compatibility guarantees, so you won't be chasing Red Herrings. The Big ABI Change is coming someday, but as of VS 2022, it's not here yet. You can freely mix and match binaries compiled with any version of MSVC in this interval (\[2015 .. 2022\]).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause exactly, but I found that the R6030 runtime error can be resolved by changing Microsoft IME 2010 to Microsoft standard IME in some computer. It may be related to Microsoft office 2010. Also, please uncheck "image protect service" at windows - start - msconfig - service tab.

Refer the following screenshots. Sorry for that the language in the screenshots is Korean.

[Microsoft IME change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCReS.jpg)

[Image Protect Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idyI4.png)

Answer (score -1):

Yes! I would recommend that you program is always delivered with the CRT you build with.

But I wonder about this. Internally the newer DLLs are binary compatible with the previous build. So because you build with the older version, the newer version "shouldn't" break you application.

I always avoid this problem in using a local installation for the VC Runtimes.

Comment: when you say local installation of VC Runtimes, are you suggesting that we copy the folders which resemble Microsoft.VC100.CRT, ATL, MFC etc  folder in the same folder where our DLL is located at the customer place and note: mine is a dll so will it first refer to this current directory and how does it know that it need to look into the folders such as Microsoft.VC100.CRT

Comment: This works only on process Level. The process controls the search path for a DLL.

Comment: can anyone suggest a solution for this , even after rebuilding the dlls with the same version that the customer is using,  this issue is not resolved , in what circumstances does MSVCR100.dll does not load MSVCP100.dll

Comment: User Depends and protocol the load order. Your DLL is loaded implicit or explicit?

Comment: My DLL is loaded Explicit, this was working fine untill a new release where the DLL was compiled on VS2010

Comment: can i include the  _DllMainCRTStartup in the linker option, MSDN says that this done by default for dlls, will adding this be of any help

Comment: This shouldn't be done by y<ou. It is set by the CRT and by the C++ Compiler. Otherwise initialisation of global vars and classes wouldn't work.

Comment: ABI stability was introduced with VS 2015. Anything before that was *"whatever"*. The *"newer should work with older"* argument has no resemblance in reality. Claiming anything else is ludicrous.